# Top navigation bar is constant while preloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a preloader on my bootstrap website but my top navbar is still remaining in it's place while the screen is loading . My aim is to have the preloading screen and then show everything on the website as it is.

How can I achieve that, any examples?

Comment: Please post what have your tried till now.

Comment: if your preloader is position:absolute or fixed, apply a higher z-index. The value should be higher than that of topbar if it have one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the most higher `z-index` on the preloader container.

**Example:**

```
.preloader-container{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Awesome Thank you very much it worked pretty well I had used z-index: 999; so it didn't work. Thanks again...

Comment: I marked it :-D
But I have one more problem with the the .js I have used to fade the preloader, doesn't seem to work pretty well, can You please with that?
I HAVE USED THIS CODE -

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
$(window).load(function(){
 $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
});

});

Comment: please create a fiddle for this

Comment: jquery version ?

Comment: ya am using version 3.2.1

Comment: Try jQuery.on('load',function(){})

Comment: Sir can You please update the jQuery.on('load',function(){}) in the fiddle please ? http://jsfiddle.net/yghpgeep/